# URL rewrite in Azure Front Door Premium

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

The rules engine identifies my intended URL fine via a condition. However the Action options - even though one says URL rewrite - only appear to allow rewrite of the path/URI. Not rewrite of the hostname.

If i wanted a rule that would always rewrite https://myhost.domain1.com/path to become myotherhost.domain2.com/path, how would i go about it?

In the FD Origin config, i have the option of setting 'origin host header' to be myotherhost.domain2.com. But that doesnt appear to be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You want to retain the path but redirect to another host, so you need to use the `URL redirect` feature than the rewrite.
In the URL redirect, you can configure "Rule set" config wherein you can define the `hostname` for which this request need to be transferred by Front Door. There are nuances of what type of redirect code you use, based on your context[ and so accordingly you need to choose 302 or 307 and so on].
See the doc [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-redirect?pivots=front-door-standard-premium) for detailed step by step configuration in Azure portal.